# SQL Server: ternary relationship

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, erd

I'm trying to implement the following scenario:

- Employee can work in different positions at the same time
- Each position is connected to a project

Note that some positions are not necessarily connected to a project (employee manager no project)

I have made a diagram to get a better view of what I need to make. See below for the diagram. From the diagram and searching on the internet. I found out that it's probably a ternary relationship. But I can't find out, how I can implement this. I'm using SQL Server in Visual Studio 2015 and use T-SQL create statements.

How can I implement this in my SQL Server database?

[image: Ternary relationship]

Comment: each position connected to at most one project ?

Comment: @CharlesBretana Yes, each position is connected to at most one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each position can only be associated with at most one project, then

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create below 3 tables. 
1. `[Employee]` - table with employee details.
2. `[Project]` - table with project details.
3. `[Position]` - table with information related to position like `PositionID`, `ProjectID`, `EmployeeID`, `CreatedDate` along with other fields. Also, create *primary key* on combination of `PositionID`, `EmployeeID` & `ProjectID` of table `[Position]`. Add foreign key constraints to prevent invalid data in `[Position]` table.